# Movie or tv series in 80s/90s which has a rooster wind vane set in a roof

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

When something is going to happen, it spins/rotate really fast. It's kind of a sci-fi/magic story. I don't remember much because I was maybe 7-10 years old when I watched it. It could be an Australian show.

Comment: Sounds like an episode of the Teletubbies; https://youtu.be/Spm1DccMiXY

Comment: And are you certain it was medieval?

Comment: I was initially thinking you were saying it was 7-10 years ago and thought about a Doctor Who [episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rebel_Flesh) with storm and weathervane plot from that period.  One of my favorite quotes ever:  "I've got to get to that cockerel before all hell breaks loose!   I never thought I'd get to say that again"

Comment: @janus: Just as a note, your question was closed as a duplicate, but that is not a censure on your part. We just try to link questions together so that it's easy to find all of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be *[Children of the Dog Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dog_Star)*, a science fiction television program for children produced in New Zealand in 1984.

> On holiday at her uncle's farm in New Zealand, Gretchen befriends Ronny, a Māori boy with a troubled city past, and Bevis the birdwatching son of a loathed developer. Tension is already high as the developer wants to buy and drain a local swamp for a housing estate, but Ronny's uncle is the guardian of a traditional Māori tapu (taboo/curse) upon the swamp. The swamp must not be touched—something sleeps there that must not be awakened. Something unnatural.
>
> In the story, twelve-year-old Gretchen has a passion for science and a talent for all things mechanical, which is why the strange old brass "weathervane" (referred to as the "daisy rod") on her uncle's farm fascinates her. But the brass daisy rod has a complex and terrifying significance, and Gretchen and her new friend Ronny discover its links with the far distant Sirius, the Dog Star.
>
> Gradually, the children discover the pieces of an ancient alien space probe named Kolob. During the series they assemble the missing parts and strange things start to happen. The probe was one of three sent to earth to educate the human race in science. In the end a communication link is set up with the star Sirius B, from where the probe came, and the aliens tell them they should not have interfered.

I can't take much credit. Searching for *science fiction tv show rooster wind vane* netted me [1980's young-adult Television show - crashed alien ship (possible A.I)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64487/1980s-young-adult-television-show-crashed-alien-ship-possible-a-i), from which I got the name of the show.

As they note, the weather vane can be seen at 2:55 of this clip. You can see it spinning at 22:43.

It does not have a rooster, but the other aspects match, and I thought maybe that detail got thrown in because you were trying to remember what a weather vane was.

Comment: Huge Tnx  FuzzyBoots .This is it. i never thought i could see this ever again. when this is 1st air i wasnt even born. i think i may have seen it around 1992 or so. cant express how grateful i am. many tnx again . chrees 

p.s i only remembers girl and a boy running and that weather vane spinning. thts all . how crazy tht i gotta watch it after all these years tnx 2 u.